# How to Capitalize first word of Every Sentence in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, text, formatting

I want the first letter of all sentences in uppercase using JavaScript, like after every full stop (.) the first character is in Uppercase.

Like this:

> This is the first sentence. This is the second sentence. This is the third sentence

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work to a good measure:

```js
text = text.replace(/(\.\s)([a-z])/g, (_, punctuation, char) => {
    return punctuation + char.toUpperCase();
});
```

A regex expression is used with two capturing groups, and [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) is used with a replace function.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const txt = "this is the first sentence. this is the second sentence. this is the third sentence";
const _txt = txt.split('.'); // split the the text into array  by "."
const _finalText = [];
for(const tx of _txt) { //loop through the array
    const _tx = tx.trim(); //trim the element since some will contain space.
    const fl = _tx[0].toUpperCase(); //take the first character of the sentence and capitalize it.
    _finalText.push(fl+_tx.substr(1)) //push the result of the concatenation of the first letter(fl) and remaining letters without the first letter into the array;
}
console.log(_finalText.join('. ')) // This is the first sentence. This is the second sentence. This is the third sentence
```

Comment: That doesn’t work, because “.” Is not only used as a sentence separator — Dr., etc., … — and sentences can be separated by other characters like ?!. Parsing sentences is a hard problem that can’t be handled by a few lines of code.

Comment: There is an error. "Uncaught TypeError: _tx[0] is undefined"

Answer (score 0):

```js
let mySentences = "this is the first sentence. this is the second sentence. this is the third sentence"

let newSentences = "";

// You can use this simple code
mySentences.split(".").map(elem => newSentences += (elem.trim().charAt(0).toUpperCase() + elem.trim().slice(1, elem.length) + "."))

console.log(newSentences)
```